# How to add beans inside arraylist into mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist, javabeans

My program is reading a lot of files which is inside a folder.All the reading parts are working fine and i am setting all the data which is readed to a bean and set.I am storing all those objects into an arraylist,when it reaches a particular limit of 900,insert it into mongodb.I am totally confused in this step.Can anyone help?

```
 ArrayList<Encapsulation> al=new ArrayList<Encapsulation>();
     Encapsulation bean=new Encapsulation();
//     bean.getId();
     bean.setId(enc.getId());
     System.out.println("id is" +bean.getId());
//     System.out.println("before inserting to db,id is"+enc.getId());
     bean.setProduct_name(enc.getProduct_name());
     bean.setProduct_url(enc.getProduct_url());
     bean.setProduct_image(enc.getProduct_image());
     bean.setProduct_price(enc.getProduct_price());
     bean.setCategory(enc.getCategory());
     //one file completely setted into a bean
     al.add(bean);
    if(al.size()>900)
    {
        System.out.println("list size>900and count is" +count++);
        obj.insertdb();
        al.clear();
    }

    public void insertdb()
    {
        for (Encapsulation s : al)
        {
            BasicDBObject document=new BasicDBObject();
            document.put("product_id", s.getId());
            System.out.println("productid is" +s.getId());
            document.put("product_name", s.getProduct_name());
            document.put("product_url", s.getProduct_url());
            document.put("product_img", s.getProduct_image());
            document.put("product_price", s.getProduct_price());
            document.put("country", "India");
            document.put("date",new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(myDate));
            document.put("category", s.getCategory());
            coll.insert(document);
            System.out.println("inserted");
        }
    }
```

The `Insertdb` method is confusing to me. I need to insert bean into mongodb.

Comment: Hi Jack, can you share what `enc` has? and How `al.size()` becomes greater than **900**? Is there any loop so that you are adding `al.add(bean);` in the loop to become size **900**?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to avoid the manual step of encoding and decoding Encapsulation instance to and from DBObject instances.  If that's the case, I suggest using one of the popular Object Document Mapper (ODM) libraries like [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) or [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki).